# Get ID of one entity and store it as an attribute for another in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a table named Family. Before inserting a new record into this table, I want to search for its parent's ID so insert as part of the new record. Is there any way I can do this.

E.g. If my table looks like

```
ID Name ParentID  
1  mark  -1  
2  eden  -1  
3  abbot  2
```

User enters "kyle abbot", I would like to search for abbot's ID which is 3 and store the new record as "4 Kyle 3" where 3 indicates the ID of the parent.

Is there any way to do this using Entity Framework?

Comment: Of course there is, but we need to see your models.

Comment: The model contains the three above mentioned attributes. ID, Name and ParentID

Comment: Well the "-1" is an issue for starters. Probably want a nullable int there. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code) is an example of a similar self referencing relationship (manager = parent, employee = child).

Comment: The parent id -1 reflects that the parent does not exist.

Comment: Dummy values are not recommended, use null if needed. See [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/NULL/116167/).

Answer (score 0):

You could query EF context using LINQ and check if the parent exists. I made an assumption from your question that the user entry contains first name and last name.

```
        var userEntry = "Kyle Abbot";

        var namePair = userEntry.Split();

        using (var ctx = new FamilyContext())
        {
            var parent = ctx.families.
                                FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(namePair[1],
                                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            var parentId = parent?.Id ?? -1;

            ctx.Add(new Family
            {
                Name = namePair[0],
                ParentId = parentId
            });

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If you add an attribute to your entity class property for the primary key, then you don't need to generate primary keys yourself to do the insertions, otherwise you need to additionally generate a primary key when you are creating new entity object to be inserted.

```
      [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```